# I set VRF chainLink fee on 0.1 LINK instead of 2 LINK on mainnet, how to fix this issue? (already deploy)

Tags: chainlink

We have deployed the VRF contract on mainnet and we added it to our main contract.
But there is issue, we set the fee limit for 0.1 LINK instead of 2 LINK, and now it look like it’s doesn’t work.
Can you give us the solution for this issue.

```
constructor  () 
    VRFConsumerBase(
      0xf0d54349aDdcf704F77AE15b96510dEA15cb7952, // VRF Coordinator     
        0x514910771AF9Ca656af840dff83E8264EcF986CA// LINK Token
    )
{
    keyHash = 0xAA77729D3466CA35AE8D28B3BBAC7CC36A5031EFDC430821C02BC31A238AF445;
   **fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK**
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only solution here is to redeploy your contracts with the correct fee set.

Code deployed to a blockchain is immutable, and since you have hardcoded the fee in it can't be changed. In the future, you could always create a setter function that can only be accessed by the contract owner that allows you to change the fee. An example:

```js
function setFee(uint256 _fee) public onlyOwner {
fee = _fee;
 }
```

This function uses the [OpenZeppelin Ownable contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol) to get the onlyOwner modifier.